# Ставить ли запятую после «точнее»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, вводные-слова, уточнения

***Приду вечером, точнее в девять часов***

У Лопатина после слова *точнее* запятая не **стоит**, что, собственно, подпадает под правило о вводных словах внутри обособленного оборота: это вводное слово, начинающее обособленный (уточняющий) оборот.

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

> § 81. Уточняющий характер членов предложения может усиливаться специальными словами вернее, точнее, иначе (они имеют значение вводных слов — см. § 91 — или в сочетании с а употребляются в значении союза, вводящего уточнение). Запятая ставится только перед этими словами, которые не отделяются от уточняющего члена предложения. Ср.: Приду вечером, точнее в девять часов — вводное слово при уточнении; Приеду осенью, а точнее в октябре — союзное сочетание; Он переутомился, а вернее болен; Отчет о том, каких высот, а точнее глубин удалось добиться в познании природы... (газ.).

***Совсем недавно, точнее, в последнем номере журнала была опубликована статья аналогичного содержания***

У Розенталя же после слова *точнее* запятая **стоит**, хотя, по-моему, по структуре они одинаковые —  в этом предложении  слова «в последнем номере журнала» имеют временное значение, уточнающее наречие «недавно».

https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

> 2. Уточняющий характер придают высказыванию слова вернее, точнее, иначе, скорее и т. п. Однако следующие за ними члены предложения не обособляются, так как указанные слова, имеющие значение вводных (точнее, вернее, иначе по смыслу равнозначны словосочетаниям точнее говоря, вернее говоря, иначе говоря), сами выделяются запятыми: Его доброта, вернее, его великодушие тронуло меня — сказуемое согласовано с ближайшим предшествующим словом, от которого оно не может быть отделено запятой; Совсем недавно, точнее, в последнем номере журнала была опубликована статья аналогичного содержания; Песец, иначе полярная лисица, ценится за свой мех (здесь иначе в значении ‘то есть’; но: Мальчика нужно вовремя остановить, иначе он такого натворит — здесь иначе выступает в функции противительного союза); Следует дополнить, скорее, уточнить приведённые в отчёте данные.

Как быть?

Comment: Конфликт, однако. Можно писать по Розенталю, а можно по Лопатину, причем в обоих случаях выбор обоснованный.  Но кто-то из них ошибается, рассуждает неверно.  Вы, кстати, за кого?

Comment: Я считаю, что и Розенталь и Лопатин ошибаются, — у обоих тема раскрыта неполно и не совсем корректно.

Comment: Я чуть позже напишу, в чем они неправы, по моему скромному мнению.

Comment: Мне кажется, важно разграничивать ситуации, когда идет уточнение, а когда — исправление. Например: «Вчера, точнее в шесть часов вечера,...» — "шесть часов вечера" сужает понятие "вчера", то есть перед нами явное уточнение, я бы применил правила Лопатина; «Он переутомился, а вернее, болен» — а вот тут слово "болен" ну никак не может уточнить слово "переутомился",  уж либо переутомился, либо болен. Здесь мы видим явное поправление автором себя: нет, он все-таки не переутомился, а болен. Таким образом, это однородные члены, между которыми располагается вводное слово. Тут я бы применил Розенталя.

Comment: @Sharon , что вы думаете о моем пояснении? Они совсем неправильные или имеют место быть?

Comment: Игорь, комментарий посмотрите в дополнении к моему ответу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ответа на вопрос  обратимся сначала **к практике письма.** Что дает нам Нацкорпус? Частотность обособленных вариантов значительно выше, приблизительная оценка 9:1. Из этого следует, что нельзя однозначно ответить, кто из авторов  прав.

Почему же приведены **различные решения**? Дело в том, что в правилах рассматриваются разные конструкции, в то время как в реальности встречаются оба их вида. Этот факт говорит о неточности и ограниченности правил  в обеих приведенных редакциях, то есть  как у Розенталя, так и в ПАС.

К тому же рассмотренные в правилах примеры имеют **упрощенную грамматику** – это скорее учебный, а не реальный материал.

Поэтому ПРИХОДИТСЯ предлагать свой вариант решения.

1. **Уточнение** – многозначное слово, мы используем его и когда сужаем значение какого-либо понятия, и когда подбираем нужно для его определения слово.  Иногда эти варианты различаются неясно, и тогда мы используем **особый «маркер» – вводное слово** ***точнее***. Обособление вводного слова зависит  от позиции оборота в предложении и от  значения оборота.
2. Если автор **обособляет** оборот **в середине предложения** (обычно при  сужении значения, но не всегда), то  слово ***точнее*** присоединяется к этому обороту, выступает в роли союза и подчеркивает уточняющее значение:

*Писатель, **а точнее поэт**, уже бесконечно долго посещал литературную студию*  [А. Б. Сальников. 2016]

...*это французская,  **а точнее парижская**, семейная марка, делающая базовые вещи замечательного качества*. [2014]

*Одновременно, **точнее еще до Есенина**, Андрей Белый выступает с неонароднической лирикой.* (2017.07.04)]

*Вот так наша затея учинить небольшой террористический акт в пропасти с треском, **а точнее с грохотом**, провалилась.* [1994]

3. Если автор **в середине предложения не обособляет оборот**, а отделяет его запятой от предыдущего слова (обычно при подборе более подходящего  понятия), то обособляется вводное слово ***точнее***, которое по смыслу при этом выполняет ту же уточняющую функцию.

*В основном переселенцы из Мордовии живут, **точнее, жили** в этом селе с названием странным, завозным ― Подустонь.* [Виктор Астафьев (1995-1996)]

*Этот разговор, **точнее, монолог продюсера** повторялся с незначительными изменениями каждую планерку.* [Елена Сафронова, 2018]

4. Если оборот стоит **в конце предложения**, то вид конструкции уже **не определяется однозначно** (обособление или разделение запятой). И в этом случае возможны оба варианта, причем выбор чаще делается **в пользу обособления**  вводного слова ***точнее***  в любом значении.

*Молодые журналисты не любят науку, **точнее, боятся её**.*

*И именно классика заставляет душу трудиться, воспитывает и просвещает её, **точнее, просветляет**.*

*Стихи я писал всегда, **а точнее, с пяти лет**.* [Роман Сеф, 2001]

5. Одно и то же предложение **при перестройке структуры** можно оформить по-разному.

Уточняющий оборот в середине предложения: *Волчица вдруг явственно услышала в себе, **точнее внутри чрЕва**, живые толчки.* (Ч. Айтматов, Плаха).

Но оборот можно перенести в конец предложения: *Волчица вдруг явственно услышала живые толчки внутри себя, **точнЕе, внутри чрЕва*** (здесь возможны варианты, но обособленный вариант будет предпочтительнее).

**ВЫВОДЫ**

Обособление  вводного слова ***точнее*** во многом зависит от позиции оборота в предложении.

1. В середине предложения уточняющий оборот (обычно с явным  значением сужения) **обособляется**, а слово ***точнее*** присоединяется к нему. При подборе нужного слова сам оборот **не обособляется**  (отделяется запятой), а **обособляется** вводное слово.  (Таким образом, обособляется всегда только  что-то одно.)
2. Для оборота, расположенного **в  конце предложения**,  возможны оба варианта, но необособленные варианты  (с любым значением) практически встречаются намного чаще.
3. При обособлении вводного слова оно выделяется **интонационно** (паузой и ударением).

Comment: Ответ блестящий, обоснованный. Вам огромное спасибо! Но для меня Розенталь всегда был неоспоримым авторитетом, а сейчас я убеждаюсь, что и он допускает неточности. Вот это правило, которое вы вывели, хоть где-то можно найти или это лишь наблюдение за языком? Если многих правил нигде нет, как поступать на экзаменах, где для проверки работ используют Розенталя и Лопатина?

Comment: Конечно, это НАБЛЮДЕНИЕ ЗА ЯЗЫКОМ. Я ответ не сразу написала – после просмотра всего материала в Нацкорпусе  формулировка изменилась. Без этого ресурса  мне приходилось нелегко. Во-первых, я сама ошибалась не раз;  во-вторых,  критиковали меня по полной программе, а возразить было нечего. КАК ВАМ БЫТЬ? Придется стать человеком «с двойным дном», то есть иметь современные углубленные знания (1)  для себя (про них пока лучше никому не рассказывать) и те знания (2), которые официально считаются правильными, а иначе никуда не поступишь.  Здесь вам только педагоги или репетиторы могут подсказать.

Comment: О РОЗЕНТАЛЕ. Когда я писала ответ, то как будто уже  слышала  ваше высказывание о Розентале и поэтому  хотела добавить в скобках (не будем забывать, что после 1994 года правила Розенталя правили другие люди).
С другой стороны, у него не было такой базы практических данных, как у нас. А что было?  Об этом он говорит в своем последнем  интервью: «Я обязан был использовать идеологические примеры…Также существовал список писателей во главе с Горьким и Шолоховым, чьи произведения я обязан был процитировать.

Comment: …Я представляю себе, сколько полетело бы голов, если бы мне вздумалось использовать примеры из Солженицына или Мандельштама!»

 https://isralove.org/load/13-1-0-2051?utm_source=copy

Comment: Премного благодарен. Нужно больше самостоятельно наблюдать за языковым материалом.

Comment: Именно. Еще немного про «наблюдения»  добавлю.  Вот Правила 1956 года, там есть предложение: "Многие наши поэты, например Жуковский, были отличными переводчиками". Тема – уточняющие обороты, а «например»  названо присоединительным словом, не вводным. Мы бы сейчас так же написали бы. А вывод какой-нибудь можно сделать?  Пожалуй,  сложно делать выводы по одному предложению. А вот наши лингвисты, ничтоже сумняшеся,  решили, что это верно  для всех уточняющих оборотов, потом – для всех  обособленных оборотов.

Comment: И к однородным членам отчего бы вводное слово не присоединить, да и к предложениям тоже. Главная задача – обобщить и упростить.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо комментария

**О Нацкорпус!** Символ века

И новейшего всего!

Трудно было человеку

Когда не было Его.

Нет, я пока не отвечаю, я пока думаю вместе с автором вопроса. Думаю о том, как **сложно было составлять  правила**, когда не было современных информационных возможностей.  И мне кажется, что многое надо **переписывать заново,** вот и эту тему тоже.

**Что правила?** Можно полистать материалы из Нацкорпуса, чтобы убедиться в  корректности  существующих правил или в отсутствии таковой. Можно даже **самим составить правило**, имея доступ к практическим материалам и учитывая базовую грамматику по теме.

Другими словами, это очень хороший и интересный вопрос. Так как всё-таки быть? Нужно ли ставить запятую после ***точнее***?

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я бы сказала так: вы **на правильном пути,** поэтому попробуйте сами ответить на вопрос.

Действительно, нужно определить вид отношений  ― уточнение или нет. **Явное отсутствие уточнения можно вычислить** (это вариант похож на подбор более удачного слова), но в других случаях будут проблемы.

Автор совершенно **не обязан учитывать уточнение**, что он и делает во многих случаях. В правилах рассмотрены очень простые предложения,  в текстах же встречаются самые разнообразные конструкции.

Вот простейшее предложение, а оно тоже имеет варианты:

(1) ***Приду вЕчером, точнее в девять часОв.*** Уточнение, две фразы, два ударения.

(2) ***Приду вЕчером, точнЕе, в девять часОв.*** Перечисление, вводное слово интонационно выделено, три ударения.

Ниже приведены примеры из Нацкорпуса (не самые лучшие, но по ним можно понять, в чем проблема.  Вроде бы по смыслу **похоже на уточнение**, но вводное слово обособлено, даже тире используется (его, кстати, можно заменить запятой).

Получается, что не **всегда автору удобно присоединять вводное слово** к будто бы уточняющему обороту. Поэтому правила кажутся формальными, в этой теме скорее нужно объяснить порядок выбора, а не задавать однозначное решение.

Я перечислю несколько предложений из Нацкорпуса, где оборот кажется уточняющим, а вводное слово обособлено отдельно.

*Эти функции берёт на себя центральная нервная система, **а точнее** ― кора головного мозга.*

*Жить он должен был в частном доме, **точнее** ― в старинном замке у человека, организующего выступление.*

*Стихи я писал всегда, **а точнее**, с пяти лет.*

Ну вот, попробуйте всё это обобщить. Удачи вам.

Comment: Да... для меня пока эта задача кажется непосильной. Мне кажется, что разница в написании обуславливается лишь различием в интонации. Или нужно копать в другую сторону?

Comment: Да, задачка не из простых, но  по крайней мере с ее половиной вы достойно справились.